# OxyPlot MajorStep is always start 0?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

this is my sample code.

```
var linearAxisX = new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                MajorStep = 0.3,
                StringFormat = "F1",
                IsZoomEnabled = false,
                IsPanEnabled = false,
                MinorTickSize = 0,
                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
                MajorGridlineColor = OxyColor.FromArgb(40, 0, 0, 139),
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
                FontSize = 10,
                MaximumPadding = 0.1,
                MinimumPadding = 0.1
            };
```

I thought it would be possible to apply Maximum, Minimum to 3.5, 4.4.
but start from 3.3.
I think MajorStep always starts at zero.

data is 
(3.5, 10)
(3.8, 10)
(4.1, 10)

This is the chart I want.
Is this impossible?

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: You can set the Minimum to 3.3 to achieve this .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already done so, but it does not work.